# laravel 5.4 combination of Neo4j, mongodb and mysql (hybrid database)

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, laravel-5, neo4j

How can I use hybrid database(neo4j, mongodb, mysql) and manage shared data between databases in laravel 5.4?

Also what is best practice for such a website:
A video learning website for K-12 student.
(Contents are Videos, Category Hierarchy for videos, video recommendation system)

- Using MongoDB for Videos
- Using Neo4J for Category Hierarchy of Contents(videos)
- Using Neo4j for video recommendation systems(base on User interests)
- Using mysql for user profile and Authentications
- Using Neo4J for social network (Users follow and Users group)

Is it possible to have these things together in Laravel 5.4 ?

Answer (score 0):

We can define multiple database connections and can name it as per our wish. Look into config/database.php.  Any number of / supported types of connections can me defined here.
Once you have connections defined, you can decide which connection to be used for model by mentioning -  protected $connection = 'connection-name'

Here are some resources :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#defining-models

http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections